# LINQ - select query in related objects Entity Framework (EF4)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

For the following (I'm using EF4) I need to select all messages in a Thread (**ContactThreadId**) that were NOT yet read given LoginId

[image]

So, i based on ContactThreadId and LoginId I need to know if this LoginId has already read all messages in a Thread. If not I need to update **ContactReadState** with all messages from the thread with his/her LoginId and when she/he read it.

I've tried these but am stuck:

```
// Update read state
var thread = this.contactMessageThreadRepository.GetRow(id);
var loginEntity = this.loginRepository.GetRow(ProfileContext.LoginId);

var unreadMsg = loginEntity.Contact
  .Where(x => x.ContactThread.Any(y => y.ContactThreadId == id))
  .Select(b => b.ContactMessage.FirstOrDefault())
  .Where(q => q.ContactReadState.Count() == 0);

var unreadMsg = loginEntity.Contact
  .Where(x => x.ContactThread.Any(y => y.ContactThreadId == id))
  .Where(y => y.ContactReadState.Any(q => q.ContactId != loginEntity.ContactId));

var msg = thread.Contact
  .Where(x => x.LoginId == loginEntity.LoginId)
  .Where(y => y.ContactReadState.Count() == 0);
```

please help.
thanks

**EDIT**:

**Login** - this table hols logins/admin records

**Contact** - this table holds all contacts (including **Login** items because Logins can also participate in a conversation-can reply to messages etc.) When a **LoginId** in a contact table is **NOT NULL**, it means it's a **Login** user otherwise it's a *public user* submitting a message.

QUESTION -> Each **Login** can have only 1 **Contact** record (I have a trigger that creates a **Contact** record upon **Login** creation). How do I make it so that it's 1 to 1.??
I've added a FK from **Contact** to **Login** table but for some reason EF created 0..1 -> * association. And it should be 1 to 1. For a given Login there can be only 1 Contact with that LoginId.

Whenever Login is viewing a list of messages a new record is inserted to ContactReadState for that Login (marking a message read by that Login (with ContactId for that Login).

Comment: Hell, your formatting was really hard to read. I hope, I've made the line breaks logically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a fragment, but can't put it completely together. Especially I don't know how you would set the `ContactId` in the new `ContactReadState` objects (see **???** below) because apparently a given `loginId` can have many contacts. So, which one to set in the new read states? Probably I misunderstood something in your model, because all those relationships look very complicated to me.

> ...based on **contactThreadId** and **loginId**...

I'm using a context directly, you need to translate this into your repository structure:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var unreadMsgs = context.ContactMessages
        .Where(cm => cm.ContactThreadId == contactThreadId
                  && !cm.ContactReadState
                         .Any(crs => crs.Contact.LoginId == loginId))
        .ToList();
    // These should be the unread messages you want to select.

    // Now, updating ContactReadState:
    foreach(var unreadMsg in unreadMsgs)
    {
        var newContactReadState = new ContactReadState
        {
            ContactMessageId = unreadMsg.ContactMessageId,
            ContactId = ???,
            ReadDate = DateTime.Now
        };
        context.ContactReadStates.AddObject(newContactReadState);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Edit**

If I understand correctly there can be contacts without login but if there is a login it is uniquely assigned to a contact.

Creating such a one-to-one relationship in EF correctly requires the following:

- You must remove the `LoginId` column and the corresponding relationship from your `Contact` table (it's the reason for the one-to-many relationship EF creates).
- The `LoginId` primary key column in the `Login` table must not be an autogenerated identity.
- You must create a foreign key relationship between `Contact` and `Login` table where the foreign key column in `Login` is the primary key column `LoginId` at the same time. So, the relationship is between `Login.LoginId` (the "dependent" with the FK) and `Contact.ContactId` (the "principal" with the PK).

This would mean that a `Login` with `LoginId=x` refers to a `Contact` with `ContactId=x` (same value) which finally makes it easy to fill the `???` in the code snippet above: `???` is simply = `loginId`.

**Edit 2**

...and of course you can replace then in the query ...

```
.Any(crs => crs.Contact.LoginId == loginId)
```

...by...

```
.Any(crs => crs.ContactId == loginId)
```

(which avoids an unnessacary join to the `Contact` table)

Comment: Slauma. I've added more info above. Also, I have another question in that new edit that maybe you can help me with. thanks

Comment: Don't you think this approach works awfully bad with even some hundreds of records? This actually means having hundreds of queries in such case. And what about thousands of records and more?